# StreamWriter not overwriting while writing a stream

Tags: c#

I have my code like this

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream ostream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Conditions.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store);

try
{
  StreamWriter swi = new StreamWriter(ostream);                        
  swi.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());
  swi.Close();   
}
```

This is in a loop, in 2nd iteration when this code runs, streamwriter appends the time to the file, I want it to overwrite.

By giving false as a second parameter i can do that but that works only when we are passing path of the file to stringwriter as first parameter.

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: what no one can help me?

Comment: Can you show me the code how you are using loop? It will help a lot to us.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileMode.CreateNew` Instead of `FileMode.Create`. So a new file will be created always.

Write down `ostream.Close()` or `ostream.Dispose()` just after `swi.Close();`

It closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use the `CreateNew` or `Truncate` Enum value of the `FileMode` in the IsolatedStorage Constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

Comment: so createnew will not work in this chekc the description, if file is already there, then it throws IOException